# Ionic MusicKitJS in App no authentification possible

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, popup, apple-musickit, apple-musickit-js

I tried to authorize a user in my App with the normal AppleMusic login popup.

```js
music.authorize().then(()=>{
  //do something
}
```

In the Webversion there poped up the Apple login form. But when I compile the App and run it on a device i think the popup is blocked or something.

How can I allow the Apple Music authorisation in my native app?

Comment: Can you try this? ``music.authorize().then(...).catch((e) => {throw e;})`` so you may get an error in console, and paste it?

Comment: The problem is the app dont goes into the catch.. I think it tries to open the popup permanently.

Comment: try an async function and awaiting the promise instead: ``async function myfunction() { await music.authorize(); console.log("Authorize finished"); }`` and see what happens. Bind the async function to a click event of a button.

Comment: still nothing happens

Comment: If nothing happens and you don't see "authorized finished" then yeah, it's stuck...

Comment: Perhaps Cordova Whitelist is blocking requests to the Apple page... check the Network tab in the inspector

Comment: in my webbrowser the app works fine. The problem is after compiling for devices.

Comment: Yes, so try debugging in your devices directly. https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/debugging

Comment: okay nothing will be blocked

Comment: There's a [thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-musickit-javascript-sdk-with-ionic/146906/9) on Ionic forums regarding this issue, maybe you can find some ideas there.